# Sorting a SynchronizedKeyCollection

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make a SynchronizedKeyedCollection and/or SynchronizedCollection sortable?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as both `SynchronizedKeyedCollection` and `SynchronizedCollection` implement `IEnumerable<T>`, Linq would be the way to go.